# RedLaser SDK on iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to build an iOS 5 app using RedLaser SDK. The RLSample app builds and runs fine. But when I try to integrate the SDK in my own app, the build goes awfully wrong. I get 48 linking errors. I noticed that the RLSample project has its "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" option set to "LLVM GCC 4.2" so I did the same in my project. But now I'm getting 11 other errors like "Expected * before *".

Anyone managed to get this working? What's the trick here?

Answer (score 0):

Linker errors would suggest that frameworks are missing; every file is compiling fine in isolation but then there are some issues glueing it all together at the end. Normally that means that the compiler's faith that some symbols will turn up eventually was misplaced. If it was a compiler error you'd get errors much earlier, and in Xcode terms you'd get errors that can take you to a specific line in your source code rather than just to some not-always-helpful compiler output.

The answer is probably to copy the linked framework list straight over from the sample project. Failing that, look up which framework each symbol should be in and add that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the frameworks linked in your build setup. Have a read of this blog post:

http://pulkitsinghal.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/integrating-with-redlaser-sdk.html